# Difference Between HUGE_VALF and INFINITY Constants

Tags: floating-point, opencl

In OpenCL, there are two floating point math constants that represent infinity.  One of them is simply `INFINITY`.  The other, `HUGE_VALF`, "evaluates to" infinity.

What is the difference between these two?  What does it mean to "evaluate to" infinity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`HUGE_VALF` is a legacy name that allows for floating-point systems that did not support infinities. For example, the C standard specifies that `HUGE_VALF` be returned in certain overflow cases. When a C implementation did not support infinities, `HUGE_VALF` would be the largest representable value. When an implementation did support infinities, `HUGE_VALF` would be infinity. The C standard still allows this, and I suppose there are some implementations around that still do not support infinities.

OpenCL uses IEEE 754 (more or less), so it does have infinities, so `HUGE_VALF` is infinity. By defining `HUGE_VALF`, OpenCL helps to support old C code being ported to OpenCL.

Regarding the wording that says “`HUGE_VALF` evaluates to +infinity” but `INFINITY` is “A constant expression of type float representing positive or unsigned infinity”, I would wonder whether that is intended to allow for some run-time preparation of `HUGE_VALF` (e.g., expressing it as `1./0.`). However, the [documentation](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/opencl-1.2.pdf) also says that `HUGE_VALF` is “A positive float constant expression.” On the balance, that makes me think the wording is simply a bit sloppy, and that `HUGE_VALF` and `INFINITY` are equivalent.