# Should I prefer HUGE_VAL or INFINITY?

Tags: c++, infinity

I've been wondering about the exact difference between the `HUGE_VAL` macro constant and the `INFINITY` one, which is also discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557691/difference-between-huge-valf-and-infinity-constants). It does seem that the two are functionally equivalent.

Is there any reason to prefer one over the other, aside from maybe distinguishing logically from a finite but huge value and a truly infinite value?

In particular, the use case I'm having now is about the kind of algorithms that need to find a max, and at the start they initialize the currently found max to `-INFINITY`. `-HUGE_VAL` could ever be preferable? If you have suggestions about other cases of usage please still tell them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With C++, you should use the `std::numeric_limits<T>` classes defined in the  header instead of these macros.
Here's an example :

```
double val = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
```

The classes are specialized for each numeric types supported by your implementation, i.e. char, int, long, float, double etc.

The max value given by those is particularly useful for finding a maximum value, as they are literally the greater value that can be represented by the queried type.

Comment: or `std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity()`

Comment: That's true, and I think using one or the other will not make any difference in real-world use.